# Не изменяются свойства дочерних элементов при наведении на родителя

Tags: html, css

Есть блок

```
 <div class="shiping-box">
   <div class="shiping-info">
     <h3 class="shiping-box-title">1</h3>
     <p class="shiping-box-text">2</p>
   </div>
   <img src="img/shiping/docs.png" class="shiping-img">
 </div>
```

По дефолту `.shiping-box-text` имеет свойство `display:none;`, при наведении пытаюсь задать `display:block;`, но он почему то игнорируется. Так же не сдвигается изображение.

```
.shiping-box:hover img.shiping-img{
    right:0;
    transition:1s;
}
.shiping-box:hover  .shiping-box-text{
    display:block;
}
.shiping-img {
    right: -10rem;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Почему так? Как можно добиться нужного результата?

Answer (score 0):

Все работает:

```css
.shiping-img {
    right: -10rem;
    position: absolute;
}

.shiping-box-text {
  display: none;
}

.shiping-box:hover img.shiping-img{
    right:0;
    transition:1s;
}
.shiping-box:hover  .shiping-box-text{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="shiping-box">
   <div class="shiping-info">
     <h3 class="shiping-box-title">1</h3>
     <p class="shiping-box-text">2</p>
   </div>
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" class="shiping-img">
</div>
```

Comment: У меня же, почему-то, не хочет.

Comment: Видимо, дело, возможно, в заданных свойствах в другом  месте?

Comment: @ВиталийRS,  да возможно